# keydown event cant get exact length

Tags: c#, winforms

i want to ask, when iam using event keydown with counting the length of the text, it doesn't match. but when i press enter or backspace it become `9`.
is there a way to make it count start from `1` instead of `0`.

the code i use

```
private void textEdit1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.textEdit1.Text.Length == 10)
        {
            textEdit2.Text = textEdit1.Text;                
            this.textEdit1.Text = "";

        }
        label2.Text = textEdit1.Text.Length.ToString();
        label1.Text = textEdit2.Text.Length.ToString();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You have to try the same in [Key_Up](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

```
private void textEdit1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.textEdit1.Text.Length == 10)
    {
        textEdit2.Text = textEdit1.Text;                
        this.textEdit1.Text = "";

    }
    label2.Text = textEdit1.Text.Length.ToString();
    label1.Text = textEdit2.Text.Length.ToString();
}
```

Because [Key_Down](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx) will get executed as and when a key will be pressed and before you release the key.

And on other side [Key_Up](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup(v=vs.110).aspx) will get executed after you release the key on a keyboar so a typed character will be there in the textbox and you will get the desired result you want.

Comment: i did use other event of previewkey down.. is it the same ? i try to read some information on internet but i dont quiet get it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that KeyDown-event is raised before Text-property is updated. If you need the length of the text after your key was processed you need to subscribe to another event, e.g. TextChanged.